# How to create a prediction/decision model when decisions can impact future observations?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, finance, mathematical-modeling, decision-theory

Apologies if this is not the correct topic for this question.

I am looking for a general approach/potential references/terms to search for regarding the following situation or similar situations as it seems like there should be references on it, but I haven't been able to find them.

Let's say that we're observing the real-time last
traded prices for some asset, denoted as $s_0, s_1, \dots$

First, we observe $s_0.$

Then, we use some predictive model, $P$, to generate a prediction (point, probabilistic, or otherwise) for $s_1$: $$p_1 = P(s_0)$$

Then, we use some decision model, $D$, to decide on an action to take based on the previously generated prediction:
$$ d_1 = D(p_1)$$

Then, for the sake of addressing the question, assume that $d_1=-1$ or $d_1=1$, representing the action of either shortselling or buying one unit of the asset at market price, respectively.

This is where my intuition for how to address this situation breaks down.

By acting on $p_1$ through either shortselling or buying a unit of the asset (and assuming we have instant execution of our order), we affect the value of $s_1$ as we decided how to enter the trade  through $d_1$ based on our prediction $p_1$.

I feel like this overlap would create potential problems with regards to evaluating the performance of the predictive and decision models.

Is there any framework for evaluating predictions and decisions when the decisions can affect future observations (that we're comparing the predictions against) utilizing only the observations recieved over time? or is this just one of the disadvantages of using something like transaction data versus modeling something with more detail regarding the impact of a trade such as the limit order book?

Comment: Broadly speaking, what you're talking about falls within the context of [operations management theory](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/operations-management.asp). There are mathematical models for decision-making within that context that can account for feedback loops and probabilistic aspects. One can even add in gaming theory aspects.

Comment: @Raskolnikov wow, thank you! I will look into that. That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. Would you happen to have on hand any good references or should searching for that field likely bring up some useful resources?

Comment: specifically pertaining to the models that address feedback loops

Comment: Sounds like a reinforcement learning setup, where future states depend on prior actions

Comment: To be honest, this is not my domain of expertise and I only came into contact with the field through helping 1st year economics students with a course in it. Evidently, the course was rather basic and skimmed only over the surface. I'm afraid I don't remember what textbook they used for it, I only know that it covered many topics including: linear programmation, queuing theory, game theory, operations management, etc... If I can find back what it was, I'll post it.

Comment: A related field you might look into is [systems engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_engineering).

Comment: I managed to find the [book](https://itslearningakarmazyan.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/operation-research-aplications-and-algorithms.pdf). The chapter that will interest you the most directly is probably chapter 13. 15 and 16 are also closely related.

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo Ah, yes, good point, this does seem like it would be suited for reinforcment learning, however, I think I am looking for if there is a bit less generalized setup that would end up being a bit more implementable in practice without the larger overhead of reinforcement learning, but theoretically, yes, I think this works.

Comment: Great and thank you so much for the references, @Raskolnikov, this gives me a lot to piece through. :)

Comment: @QMath While I agree reinforcement learning can get messy, you could start with a simple setup and then see where it needs additional complexity to be useful in practice

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo Fair point, currently looking into this more based on your recommendation, thanks!